# System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Data.SqlClient not supported on platform after framework upgrade to .NET 6

Tags: .net, docker

I recently upgraded our background application from .NET 3 to .NET 6, and I've encountered an issue while running unit tests on TeamCity using Linux Agent. The error message I'm getting is:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException : System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.
```

I've included the relevant parts of the Dockerfile, unit test configuration, and the .csproj files for both the project and unit tests below for you to have a look at.

**Part that changed in Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS builder
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:6.0-alpine3.14
```

**Part that changed in test-unit.DockerFile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
    
# install the report generator tool
RUN dotnet tool install dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool --version 5.1.10 --tool-path /tools
RUN dotnet tool install --global altcover.global
```

**Project.csproj**

```xml
        <PropertyGroup>
          <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
          <RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-musl-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
        </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
          <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.4" />
            <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />
            <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0" />
            <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

**unittest.csproj**

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Any insights on what changes I need to make in this case would be greatly appreciated.

minimal reproducible example :

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
    
    [Sql Test]
    public class SqlClient
    {
        [Test]
        public void SqlConnectionTest() 
        { 
        var connectionString = "connection_string_url";
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
            { // test logic using SqlConnection // For example, open the connection and perform some queries connection.Open();} 
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked it you use `System.Data.SqlClient` somewhere?

Comment: Also see [this breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#microsoftdatasqlclient-is-used-instead-of-systemdatasqlclient)

Comment: Yes, System.Data.SqlClient is used in the code and also when replacing it with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, getting the same error

Comment: Do you have a [mre]?

Comment: Hi @GuruStron  , I've updated the code with a minimal, reproducible example. Could you please take a look? Let me know if anything else is needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post at github or somewhere like it. And steps how do you exactly run it.